# Lenovo output sound disabled Window 10

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-update, lenovo-laptop

I have faced this issue on my laptop which stop my output device. [image]

I can't figure out the problem, I think it happened after a Windows security update installed. I tried:

1. Update Driver not worked
2. Windows Troubleshooting not found any problem

[image]

It can't detect my Output device:

[image]

Comment: Just to check, confirm that if there's a setting for On-Board Audio, it's not accidently disabled in the Firmware Setup (BIOS/UEFI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**   Sound disabled.

This is a not likely a Windows 10 update issue (I have 2 Lenovo laptops and 1 Lenovo desktop here and sound is fine).

**First:**  Go to the Lenovo Support site for your specific model. Download and install the newest version of Lenovo System Update. Run System Update and update all drivers including BIOS. The latter has to be done by itself. There will be a final restart after all this.

**Second:** Run the Windows 10 initial repairs.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator .

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  .

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  .

SFC /SCANNOW  .

Restart after all the above and test your sound.

If you still do not have sound, then there are deeper issues (non-compliant software, Windows 10 Repair Install needed).

**Third:** If everything above fails, then you may have (a) a damaged Windows User Account (not repairable by ordinary Windows 10 Repair Install) or (b) some other operating system / application damage.

Obtain or make (on your system) the Lenovo USB Recovery Key, back up all your data, and then use the Recovery Key to re-install Windows 10. Then restore your apps and data.

Comment: I tried these soltuions, but none of them solved my problem including Windows repair in windows Advanced startup.

Comment: If everything above has failed, then you may have a  corrupted User Account (ordinary Windows repair cannot fix this) or other major issue.  I amended my answer above.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was solved by your third solution, but I use the reset system that existed in the Troubleshooting of windows advanced startup.